# Why are all my Outlook autocomplete email addresses suddenly missing?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, autocomplete, contacts, pst

I have exported all the data (emails, calendar, contacts etc.) from one Outlook PST file into a new PST file, and am now using this new file instead.

Everything is working well, except now my auto-complete is blank. When I start typing an email address, no suggestions are offered.

I didn't delete or rename an NK2 file, so I'm not sure why my auto-complete entries would disappear.

Can anyone explain what happened?

Comment: What's the question? Is everything working well or not? Hard to understand what you are asking here.

Comment: What are you trying to ask?

Comment: Why would the dropdown list be blank if I didn't touch the NK2 file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have to re-import your suggested contacts.

1. Open a new email message and click on the word To, next to where you would type email addresses.
2. Use the dropdown box at the top of the window to select Suggested Contacts (if there is more than one, repeat the procedure for each)
3. Click on the top contact, then shift-click on the last to select all of them.
4. Click the 'To' button at the bottom of the window, then press OK (all your contacts will now be in the to box). At this point, the auto-complete list is updated.
5. Close the message without sending
6. ???
7. Profit

Comment: My favourite part was step 8.

Comment: Thanks- that worked. Got all my 733 contacts back in the auto-complete list. I didn't need to press Alt + K though. Skipped that step. It seems the auto-complete list gets updated when going from the "Select names" window back to the main composition window. Whatever contacts were in the To, CC or BCC fields get dumped in the auto-complete list at that point, without needing Control + K.

Comment: The Alt+K thing is only needed in some versions of outlook. I included it as I didn't know which version you were using.

Answer (score 2):

There are no KN2 files in Office 2010 to keep the autocomplete email addresses.

In Office 2010, they are kept in a separate contacts group called "Suggested Contacts", you need to export and import them as well.

[image]

In order for the Suggested Contacts to work, you also need to enable the following checkbox:

[image]

Comment: There are 733 suggested contacts showing up already, so everything got moved into the new PST file. I've got a good feeling about this. They're definitely here. I just need to make Outlook recognize them!

Answer (score 0):

My dropdown Outlook contact list wouldn't show up when typing first letter of contact name when using Chrome browser.

Solution that worked for me was pressing "ctrl + -" while in inbox and changing size to 90%.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; however, I fixed it. Click on file, options and then, mail. Under mail, scroll down until you reach "send messages" - check the last box (use auto-complate list to suggest names when typing in the to, cc, and bcc lines).